# Heroku app login only works on dev PC and not on any other device (Node.js, Passport.js)

Tags: node.js, mongodb, authentication, heroku, passport.js

I have recently deployed an app on Heroku. It works fine in the dev environment and it works fine when I access it through my PC. I cannot log into the app on any device that is not my development PC. I can post to MongoDB Atlas on any device no problem, so the database looks like it is connected and able to receive information. I looked at another answer for a similar problem from a different user and the reply was

"After looking at your repo, I would double check your database and API calls. In your client, you are fetching data from a localhost URL. If you are running React client side, the API call will try to fetch information locally on your device instead of from the Heroku server."

I don't know what the fix would be if there is something wrong with my calls. The MongoDB Atlas Database is recording the registration information no problem.

this is the github link:
https://github.com/chrishjung/Armada-Development-master

this is it on Heroku:
https://armada-phr.herokuapp.com/

**UPDATE:**
So somehow for a short period of time, I was able to register users and login after I commented out "secure: true", but now it does not work again.

snippets from app

````
// Init Session
app.use(
  session({
    secret: process.env.SESSION_SECRET,
    resave: true,
    saveUninitialized: true,
    proxy: true, // add this line
    cookie: {
      //secure: true, It worked for a short time when I commented this out
      httpOnly: true,
    },
    store: new MongoStore({ mongooseConnection: mongoose.connection }),
  })
);

// For Passport JS Authentication
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());
require("./utils/passport.auth");

app.use((req, res, next) => {
  res.locals.user = req.user;
  next();
});

//passport.auth:
const passport = require('passport');
const LocalStrategy = require('passport-local').Strategy;
const User = require('../models/user.model');

passport.use(
  new LocalStrategy(
    {
      usernameField: 'email',
      passwordField: 'password',
    },
    async (email, password, done) => {
      try {
        const user = await User.findOne({ email });
        // Username/email does NOT exist
        if (!user) {
          return done(null, false, {
            message: 'Username/email not registered',
          });
        }
        // Email exist and now we need to verify the password
        const isMatch = await user.isValidPassword(password);
        return isMatch
          ? done(null, user)
          : done(null, false, { message: 'Incorrect password' });
      } catch (error) {
        done(error);
      }
    }
  )
);

passport.serializeUser(function (user, done) {
  done(null, user.id);
});

passport.deserializeUser(function (id, done) {
  User.findById(id, function (err, user) {
    done(err, user);
  });
});

//auth.route.js
router.get(
  "/login",
  ensureLoggedOut({ redirectTo: "/" }),
  async (req, res, next) => {
    try {
      return res.render("login");
    } catch (e) {
      console.log("e", e);
    }
  }
); 
router.post(
  "/login",
  passport.authenticate("local", {
    failureRedirect: "/auth/login",
    failureFlash: true,
  }),
  async (req, res) => {
    try {
      res.redirect(`/`);
    } catch (e) {
      console.log("e", e);
    }
  }
);```
````

Answer (score 0):

After successfully deploying your app to heroku you get a url link to your app ..
You find this url in your app settings in heroku.
After finding it , Copy that url and use it by replacing the "http://localhost:××××" by the new url

Comment: I don't understand how this will make the login work. I can access the app itself. it is just communicating with my MongoDB weird.